# Scanning nested objects' array for matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object that looks like this -

```
{
"Campaigns":
{
"Campaign1":
{
    "reports":
        [
            {
                "month": "Google - January - Monthly Report.csv",
                "impressions": 53,
                "clicks": 31,
                "cost": 18
            },
            {
                "month": "Google - April - Monthly Report.csv",
                "impressions": 13,
                "clicks": 11,
                "cost": 8
            }
        ]
    },
"Campaign2":
{
    "reports":
        [
            {
                "month": "Google - March - Monthly Report.csv",
                "impressions": 13,
                "clicks": 11,
                "cost": 8
            }
        ]
}
}
```

}

And I have an additional array with file names.. let's take for an example this array -

```
reports_array = [
                 'Google - January - Monthly Report.csv',
                 'Google - February - Monthly Report.csv',
                 'Google - March - Monthly Report.csv',
                 'Google - April - Monthly Report.csv'
                 ]
```

What I wish to accomplish is to scan for 'missing' reports in every campaign (in this case 'Campaign1' and 'Campaign2') and to push a new report with zeros in all the properties (impressions, clicks, cost), So campaign1 will have february and march reports in addition to its' january and april reports, only with zeroes instead of real data. And campaign2 will have additional three reports (january, february and april) also with zeroes instead of real data.

What i tried so far (with not much of a success) -

```
reports_array.forEach(function(arr_report) {
    for(let campaign in campaigns) {
        if(campaigns[campaign].hasOwnPropert('reports')) {
            campaigns[campaign].reports.forEach(function(report) {
                if(report.month !== arr_report) {
                    console.log('campaign '+campaign+' is missing '+arr_report);
                    campaigns[campaign].reports.push({
                       month: arr_report,
                       impressions: 0,
                       clicks: 0,
                       cost: 0
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does the order of the insertion matters???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
var campaigns = campaigns_object.Campaigns;

Object.keys(campaigns)
  .forEach(function(campaign) {
    reports_array.forEach(function(report, index) {
      var has_report = campaigns[campaign].reports.some(function(campaign_report) {
        return (campaign_report.month === report);
      });

      if (!has_report) {
        campaigns[campaign].reports.splice(index, 0, {
            month: report,
          impressions: 0,
          clicks: 0,
          cost: 0
        });
      }
    });
  });

console.log(campaigns);
```

which gives you this result:

```
{
  "Campaign1": {
    "reports": [
      {
        "month": "Google - January - Monthly Report.csv",
        "impressions": 53,
        "clicks": 31,
        "cost": 18
      },
      {
        "month": "Google - February - Monthly Report.csv",
        "impressions": 0,
        "clicks": 0,
        "cost": 0
      },
      {
        "month": "Google - March - Monthly Report.csv",
        "impressions": 0,
        "clicks": 0,
        "cost": 0
      },
      {
        "month": "Google - April - Monthly Report.csv",
        "impressions": 13,
        "clicks": 11,
        "cost": 8
      }
    ]
  },
  "Campaign2": {
    "reports": [
      {
        "month": "Google - January - Monthly Report.csv",
        "impressions": 0,
        "clicks": 0,
        "cost": 0
      },
      {
        "month": "Google - February - Monthly Report.csv",
        "impressions": 0,
        "clicks": 0,
        "cost": 0
      },
      {
        "month": "Google - March - Monthly Report.csv",
        "impressions": 13,
        "clicks": 11,
        "cost": 8
      },
      {
        "month": "Google - April - Monthly Report.csv",
        "impressions": 0,
        "clicks": 0,
        "cost": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wfya0ycs/3/**

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fill(campaigns, reports) {
  for(var key in campaigns) {                                  // for each campaign in the campaign object
    reports.filter(function(report) {                          // filter out the missing reports
      return campaigns[key].reports.every(function(creport) {  // if every report in this campaign's reports array is not equal to this report, then it's is considered missing
        return creport.month !== report;
      });
    }).forEach(function(report) {                              // then for each report in the missing reports array
      campaigns[key].reports.push({                            // push a new blank report
        "month": report,
        "impressions": 0,
        "clicks": 0,
        "cost": 0
      });
    });
  }
}

var campaigns_object = {"Campaigns":{"Campaign1":{"reports":[{"month":"Google - January - Monthly Report.csv","impressions":53,"clicks":31,"cost":18},{"month":"Google - April - Monthly Report.csv","impressions":13,"clicks":11,"cost":8}]},"Campaign2":{"reports":[{"month":"Google - March - Monthly Report.csv","impressions":13,"clicks":11,"cost":8}]}}},
    reports_array = ["Google - January - Monthly Report.csv","Google - February - Monthly Report.csv","Google - March - Monthly Report.csv","Google - April - Monthly Report.csv"];

fill(campaigns_object.Campaigns, reports_array);

console.log(campaigns_object);
```